# create columns from records in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I have a df I want to occupy 2 columns:

[image]

I would like to get another df that groups the dates and gives me the category totals.

[image]

how can i do this in python

Comment: Please provide sample in reproducible format so we can work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work

```
import pandas as pd
df.pivot_table(index='date', columns='category', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
```